# Logstash cannot consume from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, apache-zookeeper

My structure is like this: Logfiles > Filebeat > Kafka > Logstash > Elasticsearch > Kibana

But I am stuck at the Kafka to Logstash part.

First, Filebeat can produce the message to Kafka and i can check it by using:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic {topicName} --from-beginning
```

And it can also be consumed by command:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic {topicName}
```

However, when I try to use logstash to consume the topic, nothing can be retrieved and Zookeeper keep throwing:

> 2017-11-13 16:11:59,205 [myid:] - INFO 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] -
>   Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:53201
>
> 2017-11-13 16:11:59,207 [myid:] - WARN 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:21 81:NIOServerCnxn@383] -
>   Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
>
> 2017-11-13 16:11:59,209 [myid:] - INFO 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] -
>   Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:53201 (no session
>   established for client)

Also, the port number in this statement keep increasing"Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:**53201**". Is it scanning the port?

Below are some background.
Version:

> zookeeper-3.4.11
>
> kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1
>
> logstash-5.4.0
>
> (Plugin)logstash-input-kafka (5.1.6)

And here are my config:

Zoo.cfg (zookeeper)

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
clientPort=2181
```

server.properties (Kafka)

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181
```

logstash.config (logstash)

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "localhost:2181"
        topics => "test"
    }   
}
```

I guess the problem is due to the config between zookeeper and kafka but i have no idea how to figure it out. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `localhost:9092` for configuration parameter `bootstrap_servers` - you're pointing Logstash to Zookeeper, but you need to point to Kafka itself.

Another error is that `topics` requires an array, so it should be `["test"]` instead of `"test"`

Comment: Thanks Alex! i changed to point at kafka directly, but still consume nothing from kafka.Is there any setting I missed? 
(i keep sending new entry to kafka)

Comment: Sorry, missed another error - `topics` is an array - updated answer

Comment: it works now!
topics => "test" to topics => ["test"]